# How to install Lmms on Centos 7

Tags: centos7, yum, lmms

I`m very new to Linux.
well, I found this link: 
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/nux-dextop-x86_64/lmms-1.1.3-2.el7.nux.x86_64.rpm.html

I tried to install lmms and lmms-vst
but it keeps requiring libwine.so.1 package

```
Error: Package: lmms-vst-1.1.3-2.el7.nux.i686 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libwine.so.1(WINE_1.0)
Error: Package: lmms-vst-1.1.3-2.el7.nux.i686 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libwine.so.1
```

Which does not exist I suppose?

```
# sudo yum install libwine.so.1

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.isoc.org.il
 * epel: rep-epel-il.upress.io
 * extras: mirror.isoc.org.il
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.isoc.org.il
No package libwine.so.1 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I tried to install this package: https://pkgs.org/download/libwine.so.1
which for centos 7 is this one: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-armhfp/wine-core-4.0.4-1.el7.armv7hl.rpm.html

But the error keeps shows up: libwine.so.1 still missing.

Thank you so much for helping:)